# Yeoman and webapp generator. What next?

Tags: yeoman

I'm completely new in Yeoman. There are a lot of different articles about a scaffolding of webapp in the Internet. However, there is nothing about the next step.
What should I do? Does webapp mean that I should use only one page (index.html)? If not, how can I add more pages (e.g. news.html, about.html)?

Sorry if any mistakes. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Webapp generator contains basic HTML boilerplate code with some basic gruntjs functionality, It will be starting point for webapp with proper structured directory.

To adding new page to webapp you have to add manually the pages to the directory

Note. Using webapp need proper understanding of gruntjs to utilize proper of power webapp-generator